# Shape Mistmatch on Validation Data givent to fit() function on Keras Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have 1 dataset (MNIST btw), splitted into train and test, both have exactly the same shape. I train a convolutional Autoencoder on on the train part and use the other for validation as seen below in the fit() function call.

The code works perfectly(i.e. model train on train data and provides good results) if I remove the `validation_data=(x_test,x_test)`
But I have to use validation_data, the problem is when I use them, after the first epoch, when the loss gets calculated on the train data and needs to be calculated for the test data, I get an error:

> Epoch 1/5  896/1000 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss:
>   0.6677--------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Tensor must be 4-D with last dim 1, 3, or 4, not
>   [1,3,3,8,8,1]
>            [[Node: conv2d_3/kernel_0_1 = ImageSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, bad_color=Tensor,
>   max_images=3

How can I resolve that?

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
print("+++++++++++++++shape of x_train " , x_train.shape)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
# adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))
# adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))

#TODO remove after i have solved the problem with the dim mismatch when using the validation dataset
x_train = x_train[range(1000),:,:,:]
x_test = x_test[range(1000),:,:,:]

# execute this in terminal to start tensorboard and let it watch the given logfile
# tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/autoencoder

tensorboardPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"tensorboard")
tensorBoard = TensorBoard(log_dir=tensorboardPath,write_graph=True,write_images=True,histogram_freq=1, embeddings_freq=1, embeddings_layer_names=None)
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"tensorboard"), verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
            epochs=5,
            batch_size=128,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(x_test,x_test),
            callbacks=[tensorBoard, checkpointer])`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out where the problem is.
Apparently, when using tenorboard callbacks with the write_images set to true.
There is a problem with writing visualisations of the convolutional layers as images. Because there is a dimension mismatch. As I understood, such debugging data are written out in case validation data are available. If I set the write_images to false, all works fine.